# Command 'python' not found after creating conda environment

Tags: bash, python, anaconda, conda

I am running Ubuntu 19.10 on my laptop, I recently installed miniconda3. No problems this far, but after creating an environment with python 2.7 I get the following message everytime I open a terminal:

```
Command 'python' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install python3         # version 3.7.5-1, or
sudo apt install python          # version 2.7.17-1
sudo apt install python-minimal  # version 2.7.17-1
```

So I followed the advise and installed python, then this error occured:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
ImportError: No module named conda
```

My guess is that bash is trying to access the conda python 2.7?
Here is what I get by running `which python` without conda active:

```
which python

/usr/bin/python

which python3

/usr/bin/python3

whereis python

python: /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python3.7 /usr/bin/python3.7m /usr/bin/python /usr/lib/python3.8 /usr/lib/python2.7 /usr/lib/python3.7 /etc/python2.7 /etc/python3.7 /etc/python /usr/local/lib/python2.7 /usr/local/lib/python3.7 /usr/include/python3.7m /usr/share/python /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz
```

with conda activated here are the corresponding results:

```
which python

/home/rustax/miniconda3/bin/python

which python3

/home/rustax/miniconda3/bin/python3

whereis python

python: /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python3.7 /usr/bin/python3.7m /usr/bin/python /usr/lib/python3.8 /usr/lib/python2.7 /usr/lib/python3.7 /etc/python2.7 /etc/python3.7 /etc/python /usr/local/lib/python2.7 /usr/local/lib/python3.7 /usr/include/python3.7m /usr/share/python /home/rustax/miniconda3/bin/python3.7-config /home/rustax/miniconda3/bin/python3.7m /home/rustax/miniconda3/bin/python3.7 /home/rustax/miniconda3/bin/python3.7m-config /home/rustax/miniconda3/bin/python /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz
```

This is what conda adds to the .bashrc file:

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/home/rustax/miniconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/home/rustax/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/home/rustax/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/home/rustax/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide

Comment: Same question asked there https://askubuntu.com/questions/1196338/strange-message-when-i-open-a-terminal Clearly an Anaconda issue. Apparently, Anaconda is messing quite a bit with a system. Could you list the changes that Anaconda does to your .bashrc file? You demonstrated it changes the PATH, but it must also be calling something that then does not find python.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that. But I have edited the question and added the lines which conda adds to .bashrc file.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for all the fuss but I have solved the problem. Since Ubuntu 19.10 doesn't come with python2 pre-installed what I did to get rid of the problem was to first remove python (since I installed it after installing conda, note that this is python and not python3 since python3 comes pre-installed) and conda completely with the following lines.

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove python

rm -rf ~/miniconda3

rm -rf ~/.condarc ~/.conda ~/.continuum
```

After this I installed python

```
sudo apt install python
```

And after installing python I installed conda the normal way and now I don't get any of the error messages posted when I open up a terminal. I guess order of PATH variables matters. Since when I had troubles I first installed conda and followed up by installing python and think that condas python path might have come first.