# Strange message when I open a terminal

Tags: command-line, apt, 18.04, python, python3

I have just installed anaconda3 in ubuntu 18.04. I have python3.7.5 in my base environment. Python 3.6.9 was already installed before anaconda installation. When I open a terminal I get the following:

```
Command 'python' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install python3       
sudo apt install python        
sudo apt install python-minimal

(base) paolo@paolo-HP-Notebook:~$
```

I wonder why that is happening and how to remove it.

Comment: do you need to add Anaconda to PATH? what happens when you add `export PATH="/root/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"` to `~/.bashrc` and then run `exec bash`?

Answer (score 0):

A default Ubuntu installation has a command `python`, which links to `python2`, which in turn links to the binary of the current version in the 2 branch. `python3` does the same for the 3-branch.

It is, therefore, not normal that you do not have a command `python`. In principle, this can be caused by 1) removal of the python 2 branch, or, 2) incidental removal of the executable (i.e., a symbolic link), or much less likely, 3) removal of the folder where `python` resides from your path.

Thus, for a start, check whether `python` is installed, and, if not, reinstall it with

```
sudo apt install python
```

Comment: Ok, I have now installed python2. Now I have python2 and python3. When I open a terminal I now get: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
ImportError: No module named conda
(base) paolo@paolo-HP-Notebook:~$

Comment: Now, this has turned into a problem with anaconda, not anymore with your system. Perhaps anaconda expects python to be version 3. So you could try replace python2 by a link to python3. Or perhaps remove anaconda and go for the python2 installer instead.

Comment: I have  uninstalled anaconda3. Now I don't get any message when I open a terminal. That's a pity not having anaconda installed. I enjoyed all that comes with the distribution.

Comment: Anaconda inserts something in your .bashrc. It does not only change your path, but apparently also launches some python script each time you open a terminal. Did you try the python3 installer? If you did, then you could still try the python2 installer, which may give good results on a distro where the default python version still is the 2 branch.

Comment: f.y.i., same question https://askubuntu.com/questions/1196316/command-python-not-found-after-creating-conda-environment. You may want to listen there.

Comment: More things get clear by reading the other thread: anaconda prepends your path with an own directory, and this way provides its own "python" executables.

Comment: As I wrote before, after uninstalling anaconda3 everything was as normal when opening a terminal. So, I I have reinstalled anaconda3 to see what happened. It still worked fine after anaconda installation. However, I tried updating anaconda with command: conda update anaconda. Then, I got again the message: 'Traceback...' after opening a terminal